# simple fade not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've made a simple box with CSS, I'm trying to fade it by dynamically changing it's opacity using the setInterval object.

http://jsfiddle.net/5gqRR/7/

CSS

```
#box {
margin:0px auto;
margin-top:10px;
height:50px;
width:50px;
background:black;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var fade;
function select(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
function disBox() {
    fade=setInterval(function(){
        select("box").style.opacity-=0.1;   
    },300);
    if (select("box").style.opacity==0) {
        clearInterval("fade");
        select("box").style.display="none";
    }   
    else {
        select("box").style.display="block";    
    }
}
```

The problem is that the "-=" operator starts subtracting the opacity from 0 instead of 1.
Can someone please explain why this happens?

Comment: Don't forget jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/5gqRR/5/ :)

Comment: I know it'd be way easier to do this with jquery but why won't this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your check about the opacity should be inside the loop.

```
function select(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}


// Run at loading
window.onload = function () {
    // Preload variables
    var box = select('box'), opacity = 1, fade;

    // Looping
    fade = setInterval(function(){
        // Calculate and applying opacity
        opacity = Math.max( 0, opacity - 0.1 );
        box.style.opacity = opacity;

        // Stoping loop when box isn't visible
        if ( !opacity )
            clearInterval(fade);
    },30);
};
```

​Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5gqRR/8/

Answer (score 1):

You can't set an `onload` event to `div` element. Instead of that you can do:

***HTML***

```
<div id="box"></div>
```

***JavaScript***

```
var fade;
function select(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
function disBox() {
    fade = setInterval(function(){
        select("box").style.opacity-=0.1;    
    },300);
    if (select("box").style.opacity==0) {
        clearInterval("fade");
        select("box").style.display="none";
    }    
    else {
        select("box").style.display="block";    
    }
}

window.onload = (function() {
    disBox();
})();
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5gqRR/4/)***

#### According to edit

```
select("box").style.opacity = 1;  // add this line to set initial opacity
fade = setInterval(function(){
            select("box").style.opacity-=0.1;    
        },300);
```

Comment: That's great advice but I used the onload event in the <body> tag in the actual page. The problem is that when I use the "-=" operator it starts subtracting the opacity from zero when it should start subtracting from 1.

Comment: @senilesage then you can try with set a `css` opacity or write `select("box").style.opacity = 1;` line before `-=` line

Comment: I don't think my question made the problem too clear so I made a few edits.